# MS SQL 2008 R2 SSAS & ASP.Net with Windows Integrated Autheotication

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-7, ssas

My requirement is to develop a ASP.Net site that allows users to access SSAS cubes for data analysis. These users belong to a Domain (MS Active Directory). The AD is situated at head office and i do not have access to it. neither can we request for any changes to the settings of the AD as it handles the multiple companies...etc.

i activated Windows authentication on my site & impersonation as well. The issue is, the connection to the SSAS is always created using the user id mentioned in the App Pool for this particular website. What's required is for the connection to be made using the uid that's validated against the AD when the user connects to this website.

Thanks & Best Regards
Chris

Comment: How do users connect to Cubes? Your site generates ODC files?

Comment: So the users connect to your website using their Active Directory credentials?

Comment: I believe this is a double-hop problem. Windows can only pass credentials from one server to the next if Kerberos is correctly configured for both services. How? Don't ask me. I do think you can avoid the problem if IIS and SSAS are on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

If your scenario is as Bill noted - which it certainly does sound like it - then the only way you can avoid the double-hop is as he had suggested, to place IIS and SSAS on the same server.

If you do need to keep IIS and SSAS on separate servers, suggest the following articles:

Configuring Kerberos Authentication for Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products
http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/whitepapers/archive/2010/07/22/configuring-kerberos-authentication-for-microsoft-sharepoint-2010-products.aspx

How to configure SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services and SQL Server 2005 Analysis Services to use Kerberos authentication http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917409?wa=wsignin1.0

HTH!